# ODR violation in GCC 6.3.0 with types defined in two separate translation units

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, one-definition-rule

We are seeing some strange behavior in GCC with the following code example. The strange behavior is ODR violation in GCC 6.3.0 with types defined in two separate translation units. It is possibly related to recursive type definitions or incomplete types.

We are unsure whether our code is valid, or if we are depending on undefined behavior in the way our types are recursively defined. Please see how the variant-like Dynamic class template is defined and instantiated in two separate cpp files.

dynamic_test.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

namespace dynamic
{
    template <class T>
    void erasure_destroy( const void *p )
    {
        reinterpret_cast<const T*>( p )->~T();
    }

    template <class T>
    void erasure_copy( void *pDest, const void *pSrc )
    {
        ::new( pDest ) T( *reinterpret_cast<const T*>( pSrc ) );
    }

    template <class T>
    struct TypeArg {};

    struct ErasureFuncs
    {
        template <class T = ErasureFuncs>
        ErasureFuncs( TypeArg<T> t = TypeArg<T>() ) :
            pDestroy( &erasure_destroy<T> ),
            pCopy( &erasure_copy<T> )
        {
            (void)t;
        }

        std::add_pointer_t<void( const void* )> pDestroy;
        std::add_pointer_t<void( void*, const void* )> pCopy;
    };

    enum class TypeValue
    {
        Null,
        Number,
        Vector
    };

    template <typename T>
    using unqual = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

    template <class Base, class Derived>
    using disable_if_same_or_derived = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<Base, unqual<Derived>>::value>;

    template <template <class> class TypesT>
    struct Dynamic
    {
        using Types = TypesT<Dynamic>;

        using Null = typename Types::Null;
        using Number = typename Types::Number;
        using Vector = typename Types::Vector;

        Dynamic()
        {
            construct<Null>( nullptr );
        }

        ~Dynamic()
        {
            m_erasureFuncs.pDestroy( &m_data );
        }

        Dynamic( const Dynamic &d ) :
            m_typeValue( d.m_typeValue ),
            m_erasureFuncs( d.m_erasureFuncs )
        {
            m_erasureFuncs.pCopy( &m_data, &d.m_data );
        }

        Dynamic( Dynamic &&d ) = delete;

        template <class T, class = disable_if_same_or_derived<Dynamic, T>>
        Dynamic( T &&value )
        {
            construct<unqual<T>>( std::forward<T>( value ) );
        }

        Dynamic &operator=( const Dynamic &d ) = delete;
        Dynamic &operator=( Dynamic &&d ) = delete;

    private:
        static TypeValue to_type_value( TypeArg<Null> )
        {
            return TypeValue::Null;
        }

        static TypeValue to_type_value( TypeArg<Number> )
        {
            return TypeValue::Number;
        }

        static TypeValue to_type_value( TypeArg<Vector> )
        {
            return TypeValue::Vector;
        }

        template <class T, class...Args>
        void construct( Args&&...args )
        {
            m_typeValue = to_type_value( TypeArg<T>() );
            m_erasureFuncs = TypeArg<T>();
            new ( &m_data ) T( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
        }

    private:
        TypeValue m_typeValue;
        ErasureFuncs m_erasureFuncs;
        std::aligned_union_t<0, Null, Number, Vector> m_data;
    };
}

void test1();
void test2();
```

dynamic_test_1.cpp:

```
#include "dynamic_test.h"

#include <vector>

namespace
{
    template <class DynamicType>
    struct Types
    {
        using Null = std::nullptr_t;
        using Number = long double;
        using Vector = std::vector<DynamicType>;
    };

    using D = dynamic::Dynamic<Types>;
}

void test1()
{
    D::Vector v1;
    v1.emplace_back( D::Number( 0 ) );
}
```

dynamic_test_2.cpp:

```
#include "dynamic_test.h"

#include <vector>

namespace
{
    template <class DynamicType>
    struct Types
    {
        using Null = std::nullptr_t;
        using Number = double;
        using Vector = std::vector<DynamicType>;
    };

    using D = dynamic::Dynamic<Types>;
}

void test2()
{
    D::Vector v1;
    v1.emplace_back( D::Number( 0 ) );
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "dynamic_test.h"

int main( int, char* const [] )
{
    test1();
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code causes a SIGSEGV with the following stack trace:

```
1 ??                                                                                                                                     0x1fa51  
2 dynamic::Dynamic<(anonymous namespace)::Types>::~Dynamic                                                        dynamic_test.h     66  0x40152b 
3 std::_Destroy<dynamic::Dynamic<(anonymous namespace)::Types>>                                                   stl_construct.h    93  0x4013c1 
4 std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<dynamic::Dynamic<(anonymous namespace)::Types> *>                           stl_construct.h    103 0x40126b 
5 std::_Destroy<dynamic::Dynamic<(anonymous namespace)::Types> *>                                                 stl_construct.h    126 0x400fa8 
6 std::_Destroy<dynamic::Dynamic<(anonymous namespace)::Types> *, dynamic::Dynamic<(anonymous namespace)::Types>> stl_construct.h    151 0x400cd1 
7 std::vector<dynamic::Dynamic<(anonymous namespace)::Types>>::~vector                                            stl_vector.h       426 0x400b75 
8 test2                                                                                                           dynamic_test_2.cpp 20  0x401796 
9 main                                                                                                            main.cpp           6   0x400a9f
```

It's odd that constructing a Vector takes us directly to a destructor.

What is very strange, is that these errors go away when we do the following:

1. Rename "Types" in one of the cpp files, so that they do not use the
   same name for the class template.
2. Make the implementation of "Types" the same in each cpp file (change
   Number to double in each file).
3. Do not push a Number to a Vector.
4. Change the implementation of Dynamic to not use this recursive type
   definition style.

Here is a trimmed down example of an implementation which does work:

```
template <class Types>
struct Dynamic
{
    using Null = typename Types::Null;
    using Number = typename Types::Number;
    using Vector = typename Types::template Vector<Dynamic>;

...

    struct Types
{
    using Null = std::nullptr_t;
    using Number = long double;

    template <class DynamicType>
    using Vector = std::vector<DynamicType>;
};
```

We also see some warnings related to ODR violation when we compile with link time optimization (LTO):

```
dynamic_test.h:51: warning: type ‘struct Dynamic’ violates the C++ One Definition Rule [-Wodr]
struct Dynamic
         ^
```

Does anyone have some insight into what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Looks like it might be internally treating them as if they were the same type; if so, it's probably a compiler bug, but I'm not 100% sure what the standard says about that.  Just a guess, though, I don't have GCC installed, and the only online GCC environment I know of that allows multiple files is outdated.

Comment: Do two differently named namespaces in the source files (instead of anonymous namespaces) fix the problem as well?

Comment: If you change the order of the dynamic_test.cpp files on the command line, does it change which test the segfault comes from?

Comment: What you should also do is provide the compiling and linking commands you use here to make your repro case complete. Also try to separate out the linking and the compiling into separate steps. After you have compiled the .o files, you should run `nm` on them. `nm` should show the symbol `Types` with a lower case t.

Comment: @JustinTime Thanks, that is our suspicioun as well, but also curious if incomplete types are a factor. We found a similar bug posted to GCC Bugzilla: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70413

Comment: @MarkB Yes, naming the namespace differently also resolves the issue.

Comment: @NirFriedman Yes, changing the ordering on the command line does change which test the segfault comes from. Also, thanks for the suggestion, I will try that.

Comment: @ethortsen If changing the ordering changes which test causes the segfault, with the second-linked test being the segfaulting one, what is most likely occurring is that the definition of `Types` from the first linked is being used in the second linked. I wouldn't expect that to happen with something that has internal linkage which is why I asked about nm. I tried to do a repro locally but I failed (different os, different gcc, who knows). You could try defining a static string for each `Types` differently and print it as part of test to try to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, it took me a while of playing with this on and off, but I finally got a very simple duplicate that gets at the heart of the matter. First, consider `test1.cpp`:

```
#include "header.h"

#include <iostream>

namespace {

template <class T>
struct Foo {
   static int foo() { return 1; };
};

using D = Bar<Foo>;

}

void test1() {
    std::cerr << "Test1: " << D::foo() << "\n";
}
```

Now, `test2.cpp` is exactly identical to this, except that `Foo::foo` returns 2, and the function declared at the bottom is called `test2` and prints `Test2:` and so on. Next, `header.h`:

```
template <template <class> class TT>
struct Bar {
    using type = TT<Bar>;

    static int foo() { return type::foo(); }
};


void test1();
void test2();
```

Finally, `main.x.cpp`:

```
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    test1();
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

You may be surprised to learn that this program prints:

```
Test1: 1
Test2: 1
```

Of course, that's only because I compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.x.cpp test1.cpp test2.cpp
```

If I reverse the order of the last two files, they both print 2.

What's happening is that the linker ends up using the first definition it encounters of `Foo` everywhere it's needed. Hmm, but we defined `Foo` in an anonymous namespace, which should give it internal linkage, avoiding this issue. So we compile just one TU and then use `nm` on it:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -c test1.cpp
nm -C test1.o
```

This yields the following:

```
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
0000000000000087 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5test1v
0000000000000049 t __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
0000000000000000 T test1()
000000000000003e t (anonymous namespace)::Foo<Bar<(anonymous namespace)::Foo> >::foo()
0000000000000000 W Bar<(anonymous namespace)::Foo>::foo()
                 U std::ostream::operator<<(int)
                 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
                 U std::cerr
0000000000000000 r std::piecewise_construct
0000000000000000 b std::__ioinit
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
```

Don't worry about the letters for now, other than upper case versus lower case. Lower case symbols are private, the way we expect internal linkage symbols to be. Upper case symbols are public, and have external linkage and are exposed to the linker.

What's interesting, and not really that surprising, is that while `Foo` may have internal linkage, `Bar` does not! The first translation unit already defines the symbol `Bar<Foo>` with external linkage. The second translation unit does the same. So when the linker links them, it sees two translation units trying to define the same symbol with external linkage. Note that it's an inline defined class member, so it's implicitly inline. So the linker handles this as it always does: it just silently drops all the definitions it runs into after the first (because the symbol is already defined; that's how the linker works, left to right).So `Foo` is correctly defined in each TU, but `Bar<Foo>` isn't.

Bottom line is that this is an ODR violation. You'll want to rethink some stuff.

Edit: it seems in fact like this is a bug in gcc. The standard's wording implies that the `Foo`s should be treated uniquely in this situation, and thus the `Bar` templated on each `Foo` should be separate. Link to bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70413.

Comment: Meanwhile, MSVC merrily does exactly what you want, because the compiler gives every anonymous namespace its own unique internal name, and thus it sees each `Bar<Foo>` as a separate entity.  (For example, compiling with VS2010 (after changing the typedefs from `using` to `typedef`, because it was faster than walking to the computer with VS2015 installed), it generates `?foo@?$Bar@UFoo@?A0x67d7c1f5@@@@SAHXZ` for `test1.cpp` and `?foo@?$Bar@UFoo@?A0xe143b35b@@@@SAHXZ` for `test2.cpp`., where each `A<hex number>` is an anonymous namespace.)

Comment: I'm curious whether MSVC is too lenient with anonymous namespaces here, or whether GCC has trouble differentiating between anonymous namespaces.

Comment: @Justin Time I'm not really sure what you mean by too lenient. I doubt this is covered by the standard at all. Most linker behavior isn't. Happy to be proven wrong though. I've come across many examples where msvcs linker is better behaved. On Linux it's hilariously easy to cause segfaults with valid code where globals, static and dynamic linking are mixed.

Comment: By "too lenient", I meant that if it was an ODR violation, then MSVC would be wrong for letting it compile; I wasn't sure whether it was an ODR violation or a bug, which is why I didn't know which compiler was at fault.

Comment: I just took a look at the standard, though, and `[namespace.unnamed/1]` says that each unnamed namespace is supposed to be treated as if it has a unique name, and that "Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage, they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit."  I may be misinterpreting, but I believe this means it's a GCC bug.

Comment: (And yeah, I've noticed that the MSVC linker is more reliable, too.  I personally think a big part of it is that their name mangling scheme is more thorough than GCC's, especially where globals and return types are concerned.  It's a lot harder to break, whether accidentally or intentionally, because it preserves basically the entire declaration.)

Comment: @JustinTime You make a good point with that standard quote, it gets pretty ambiguous what with the templating. I may re-ask this separately. Re MSVC, my biggest example is not related to name mangling. Double deletion of globals in Linux for no good reason.

Comment: Just want to say, thanks for all the feedback and help so far. @NirFriedman, your example seems to get down to the crux of the issue, and looks a lot like the example provided on GCC Bugzilla, where it looks like the bug was recently confirmed (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70413). However, it is very interesting to try to understand what the standard intends in this case.

Comment: @ethortsen My pleasure, was an interesting problem. I've edited my answer to include the highlights of the conversation in the comments and the bug link. I'm not sure there's much more to say as I'm not seeing anyone arguing against this being a bug. Let me know if there's anything else I should provide so you can mark this as accepted.

Comment: @NirFriedman I would assume that the uniqueness is supposed to remain even when members of the anonymous namespace are used as template parameters, to prevent ODR violations, but it could be worded more clearly.  I didn't know that GCC's linker had issues with double deleting globals, though, that's pretty strange.